# EMR cluster: java to jar

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, amazon-emr

I have a java script (for a Map-reduce calculation) and would like to generate a jar file on the amazon
EMR cluster, however I am not sure if this is possible? or do I have to generate the jar file
locally and then transfer it to the cluster?
Any comment, idea or command for this case is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK includes commands to build JAR files, yes, but I recommend you use Maven/Gradle to package your application code, along with its dependencies.

Transferring to the cluster is not required. For example, `yarn jar` and `spark-submit` both accept local file submissions (but then will copy the file to HDFS)